# Rails after_create make a related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a default **Category** for each **User**'s **Company**, after he creates one.

Elaborating,

```
User
  has_many :companies

Company
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :categories
```

After a user creates a new company, I would like it to have a default category.

So something like

**Company.rb**

```
after_create :create_default_category

private

  def create_default_category
    self.category.new(name: "default")
  end
```

The code above, not surprisingly, is dysfunctional. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: The `.new` function does not persist the record in the DB, you must save it after, or use `.create` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you want to create category but you have a has_many relationship - so if you wont after_create then you have to use categories.create so:

```
self.categories.create(name: "default")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_default_category
    category = self.category.new(name: "default")
    category.save
end
```